# Oracle returns ORA-00904: invalid identifier error when adding foreign keys

Tags: sql, oracle, vmware

I am unsure as to why I can't insert org_id and vol_id as foreign keys. It returns the error in the title ORA-00904: invalid identifier

```
  CREATE TABLE VOLUNTEERS (
      vol_id varchar2(3) not null, 
      vol_fname varchar2(10) not null,
      vol_lname varchar2(10) not null,
      vol_address varchar2(20) not null,
      vol_telephone varchar2(10) not null,
      primary key (vol_id)); 
      
    CREATE TABLE ORGANIZATIONS (
      org_id varchar2(3) not null,
      org_name varchar2(30) not null,
      org_contact varchar2(20) not null,
      org_address varchar2(20) not null,
      org_telephone varchar2(10) not null,
      primary key (org_id));
    
    alter table volunteers
    add foreign key (org_id) references ORGANIZATIONS; 
    
    alter table organizations
    add foreign key (vol_id) references VOLUNTEERS;
```

Comment: There is no `org_id`  column in the table `volunteers`

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE child_table
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_name
FOREIGN KEY (col_name) REFERENCES table_name(col_name);

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key constraint is a constraint *on an existing column*.  You have not defined the columns in each of the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE VOLUNTEERS (
      vol_id varchar2(3) not null, 
      vol_fname varchar2(10) not null,
      vol_lname varchar2(10) not null,
      vol_address varchar2(20) not null,
      vol_telephone varchar2(10) not null,
      org_id varchar2(3),
------^
      primary key (vol_id)
); 

CREATE TABLE ORGANIZATIONS (
      org_id varchar2(3) not null,
      org_name varchar2(30) not null,
      org_contact varchar2(20) not null,
      org_address varchar2(20) not null,
      org_telephone varchar2(10) not null,
      vol_id varchar2(3),
------^
      primary key (org_id)
 );
```

Once the columns are defined, the foreign key constraints will work.